# Cause of ExecuteError: ERROR 000539: Invalid field County Insets.OBJECTID Failed to execute (CalculateField)?

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, error-000539

The following script joins two layers on a common id and attempts to use the OBJECTID in the joined table to update records for a field in the input table.  In running it in "current" mode, it moves through the join process ok but then errors out with Calculate.  OBJECTID is from a joined table and I am joining it to an Annotation class, but I'm not sure that is relevant.  Any ideas as to why this doesn't complete?

```
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("Current")
    dflist = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)
    for df in dflist:
        if df.name == "County":
            for lyr in (arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df)):
                if lyr.name == "County Insets":
                    CoInset = lyr
                elif lyr.name == "County Insets Anno":
                    CoAnno = lyr
            print 'Joining ' + CoInset.name + ' to ' + CoAnno.name
            arcpy.AddJoin_management(CoAnno, "TempID", CoInset, "TempID")
            expression = "!" + CoInset.name +".OBJECTID!"
            arcpy.CalculateField_management(CoAnno, "FeatureID",  expression, "PYTHON")
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "<string>", line 14, in <module>   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 3129, in CalculateField     raise e <br>
ExecuteError: ERROR 000539: Invalid field County Insets.OBJECTID Failed to execute (CalculateField).
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
expression = "!" + CoInset.datasetName +".OBJECTID!"
```

instead of:

```
expression = "!" + CoInset.name +".OBJECTID!"
```

The joined fieldnames should reflect the feature class/annotation's *workspace* name, not table-of-contents name.

Comment: That was the trick! Thanks for the quick and on target response. It can be maddening trying to figure out simple syntax issues like this.  Thanks for the help!